# How to map the temperature values to corresponding RGB indexes

Tags: c, rgb

Here is my code:

```
RGB_Struct RGB_TABLE[] =
{
    /* Temperature */
    {195, 209, 255},  
    {195, 210, 255}, 
    {196, 210, 255}, 
    {197, 210, 255}, 
    {197, 211, 255},
    {197, 211, 255},
    {198, 212, 255},
    {198, 212, 255},
    {199, 212, 255},
    {200, 213, 255},
    {200, 213, 255},
    {201, 214, 255},
    {202, 214, 255},
    {202, 215, 255},
    {203, 215, 255},
    {204, 216, 255},
    {204, 216, 255},
    {205, 217, 255},
    {206, 217, 255},
    {207, 218, 255},
    {207, 218, 255},
    {205, 220, 255},
    {206, 220, 255},
    {207, 221, 255},
    {207, 221, 255},
    {208, 222, 255},
    {209, 223, 255},
    {210, 223, 255},
    {211, 224, 255},
    {212, 225, 255},
    {214, 225, 255},
    {215, 226, 255},
    {216, 227, 255},
    {217, 227, 255},
    {218, 229, 255},
    {220, 229, 255},
    {221, 230, 255},
    {222, 230, 255},
    {224, 231, 255},
    {225, 232, 255},
    {227, 233, 255},
    {228, 234, 255},
    {230, 235, 255},
    {231, 236, 255},
    {233, 237, 255},
    {235, 238, 255},
    {237, 239, 255},
    {239, 240, 255},
    {240, 241, 255},
    {243, 242, 255},
    {245, 243, 255},
    {247, 245, 255},
    {249, 246, 255},
    {252, 247, 255},
    {254, 249, 255},
    {255, 249, 253},
    {255, 248, 251},
    {255, 246, 247},
    {255, 245, 245},
    {255, 244, 242},
    {255, 243, 239},
    {255, 242, 236},
    {255, 240, 233},
    {255, 239, 230},
    {255, 238, 227},
    {255, 236, 224},
    {255, 235, 220},
    {255, 233, 217},
    {255, 232, 213},
    {255, 230, 210},
    {255, 228, 206},
    {255, 227, 202},
    {255, 225, 198},
    {255, 223, 194},
    {255, 221, 190},
    {255, 219, 186},
    {255, 217, 182},
    {255, 215, 177},
    {255, 213, 173},
    {255, 211, 168},
    {255, 209, 163},
    {255, 206, 159},
    {255, 204, 153},
    {255, 201, 148},
    {255, 199, 143},
    {255, 196, 137},
    {255, 193, 132},
    {255, 190, 126},
    {255, 187, 120},
    {255, 184, 114},
    {255, 180, 107},
    {255, 177, 101},
    {255, 173, 94},
    {255, 169, 87},
    {255, 165, 79},
    {255, 161, 72},
    {255, 157, 63},
    {255, 152, 54},
    {255, 147, 44},
    {255, 142, 33},
    {255, 138, 18},
    {255, 131, 0},
    {255, 126, 0},
    {255, 121, 0},
    {255, 115, 0},
    {255, 109, 0},
    {255, 101, 0},
    {255, 93, 0},
    {255, 83, 0},
    {255, 71, 0},
    {255, 56, 0},
};

RGB_Struct ConvertTemperatureToRGB(float temperature)
{
    uint16_t index = 0;


    return TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[index];
}

void heatmap(float *data, char *pixelDataPtr)
{
    int height = 8;
    int width = 8;
    unsigned char image[height][width][BYTES_PER_PIXEL];
    RGB_Struct rgbVaue;

    int i, j, k=0;
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            rgbVaue = ConvertTemperatureToRGB(data[k++]);
            image[i][j][0] = rgbVaue.Red;
            image[i][j][1] = rgbVaue.Green;
            image[i][j][2] = rgbVaue.Blue;
        }
    
}

}
```

In the code `create_heatmap(temp_c, Pixels);` will be called in main and `temp_c` is `float temp_c[64]` and `Pixels` is `char Pixels[246]`.

The Temperature values need to be mapped with the RGB values in `TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[]`.
For the mapping we need indexes to map the Temp data with RGB values.

Help me fix the code so that the 64 temperature values to be mapped with the RGB data according to their temperature, I'm fine to map the temperature readings between 20°C - 50°C with resolution of 0.25°c.

Comment: There are 110 values in the table shown. If you need 4 values per degree then the table only covers a range of 27.5 degrees. I would guess, assuming the temperature value is between 20 and 50, that you could subtract 20, multiply by 4, round up, and use that as the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RetiredNinja . I can increase the table count or can decrease the temperature range, that's not a big deal but I couldn't figure out how to program the index with the current code and map that index to RGB table according to the temperature values in `temp_c`. I'm kind of new to all these stuff, so seeking help with code on creating Indexes and mapping

Comment: Use whatever range and however many values you need. The key is you must map the floating point increments of `.25` degree into *integer* indexes from `0 <= i < nelem` (where `nelem` is the number of elements). So whether you have 110 values or 500 values, just figure out the mapping and range as @RetiredNinja suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidC.Rankin, I understood the logic but can't able to replicate the same with code, so seeking some help with programming. Just give 2 line code example for each of **How to create index and how to map that index to RGB with a example temperature value** and how it will be returned and stored in Pixels. Please do feel free to write as few lines as you can in respective functions. Please do apologize because I'm new and learning all these stuffs now.

Comment: Say `double temp = 1.5;` Then to get the corresponding RGB values, you will need `int index = (int)(temp / .25);`. As suggested, you can use `int index = (int)round (temp / .25);` to round a bit more formally.. (either way the result is `index = 6`) Then your RGB values are `TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[index].Red;` (and the same for `.Green` and `.Blue`)

Comment: Here you table starts as `0.0` Deg C. So the conversion for 1/4 deg increment is simply to divide by `.25`. If your RGB table started at 20 Deg C, then you would just subtract 20 and then divide by `.25` to map to the `0` index of the table. **Note:**  you would also add a check that the index was not negative and was within the range for your table (`0 <= index < 110` for 110 values). Otherwise referencing an index outside of the bounds of your table would invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Also, in your case you are using `float` for temp instead of `double`. That's fine as well. (32-bit floating point value instead of 64-bit) Using `uint16_t` for `index` is fine. You are using a 2-byte unsigned value instead of `int` (generally 4-byte signed value). Just keep your types consistent.

Comment: @Yuvi - did that make it clear? If not I can write a short answer for you. Let me know.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it's still kind of confusing. Can you please reply as answer with as few lines of code that shows comparing with one/two temperature values wiz above 20°C and   and how that value to be returned and stored in Pixels. It would be more helpful for my understanding if it is in form code and Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec and I'll write it up for you.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect example of something where you should figure out all the logic and math behind the algorithm long before you write a single line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try and make it simple, which arriving at an index is, the only difficult part is handling the inequality to arrive at the range you want, e.g.

```c
    /* Temperature */ /* RGB Value */
    {195, 209, 255},  /* <= 0.00 °C */
    {195, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.25 °C */
    {196, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.50 °C */
    {197, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.75 °C */
    ...
```

Note above, for values not zero but less than `0.25` Deg C all have the value provided by the 2nd element of the table.

Let's start with the naive case where we simply want to map the temperature to your table without worrying about the ranges. There, as mentioned in the comment, since your `0` Deg C corresponds to your `0` element of your table and your table handles temperature in `.25` Deg C increments, all you need to do is divide the `temperature` by `.25` to arrive at the `index`, e.g.

```c
 RGB_Struct ConvertTemperatureToRGB(float temperature)
{
    uint16_t index = 0;

    index = (uint16_t)(temperature / .25);
    
    return TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[index];
}
```

This will return a valid index (so long as your temperature does not result in an index beyond the end of your table. However, your returned table index will not match the range you provide in the comment. For example, above would result in the following indexes mapped for a `temperature` between `0` and `1`, e.g.

```
temp: 0.00    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.05    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.10    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.15    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.20    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.25    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.30    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.35    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.40    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.45    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.50    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.55    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.60    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.65    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.70    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.75    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.80    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.85    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.90    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.95    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 1.00    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
```

If you look, the results are off by 1 index and do not include the temps at the increments of `.25`, `.50`, ... in the proper range.

This is simply a math-problem, an inequality. One fairly straight-forward way to handle this is to define how-close you want to be to the increment before the value changes. You can define the limit and adjust the index returned by taking those values up to, but not including the next temperature increment. For example to be within `0.00005` of an increment, you can define a limit as:

```c
#define LIMIT 5e-5
```

Then to capture the range you want, computing the index becomes:

```c
      index = (uint16_t)((temperature + .25 - LIMIT) / .25);
```

Where you take all values up to within `LIMIT` of the next increment for the current index.

If you recognize that the first element in your table is for values less than or equal to zero Deg C, you can simply treat those as a special case. Your final `index` calculation them becomes:

```c
    if (temperature <= 0)
      index = 0;
    else
      index = (uint16_t)((temperature + .25 - LIMIT) / .25);
```

If you put that altogether (noting that `index` is already initialized to `0` for the `0` case), your function becomes:

```c
RGB_Struct ConvertTemperatureToRGB(float temperature)
{
    uint16_t index = 0;

    if (temperature > 0)
      index = (uint16_t)((temperature + .25 - LIMIT) / .25);
    
    return TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[index];
}
```

Now, check how the values fall and compare to the desired results, e.g.

```
temp: 0.00    R: 195  G: 255  B: 209
temp: 0.05    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.10    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.15    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.20    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.25    R: 195  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.30    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.35    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.40    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.45    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.50    R: 196  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.55    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.60    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.65    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.70    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.75    R: 197  G: 255  B: 210
temp: 0.80    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
temp: 0.85    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
temp: 0.90    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
temp: 0.95    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
temp: 1.00    R: 197  G: 255  B: 211
```

Which according to your comments, matches the desired indexing. There isn't any magic to how you set your math up -- you can do it any number of ways, so long as you are capturing the correct range of values in the proper index. It's basically just a scaling problem.

**Example Code**

To verify, the following code is a simple, minimal, bit of code from your question:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Red;
    uint8_t Blue;
    uint8_t Green;
} RGB_Struct;

/**
 * Temperature range of measuring object = 0 °C to 80 °C (or) +32 °F to +176 °F
 * with resolution = 0.25 °C
 */
RGB_Struct TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[] =
{
    /* Temperature */ /* RGB Value */
    {195, 209, 255},  /* <= 0.00 °C */
    {195, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.25 °C */
    {196, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.50 °C */
    {197, 210, 255},  /* <= 0.75 °C */
    {197, 211, 255},
    {197, 211, 255},
    {198, 212, 255},
    {198, 212, 255},
    {199, 212, 255},
    {200, 213, 255},
    {200, 213, 255},
    {201, 214, 255},
    {202, 214, 255},
    {202, 215, 255},
    {203, 215, 255},
    {204, 216, 255},
    {204, 216, 255},
    {205, 217, 255},
    {206, 217, 255},
    {207, 218, 255},
    {207, 218, 255},
    {205, 220, 255},
    {206, 220, 255},
    {207, 221, 255},
    {207, 221, 255},
    {208, 222, 255},
    {209, 223, 255},
    {210, 223, 255},
    {211, 224, 255},
    {212, 225, 255},
    {214, 225, 255},
    {215, 226, 255},
    {216, 227, 255},
    {217, 227, 255},
    {218, 229, 255},
    {220, 229, 255},
    {221, 230, 255},
    {222, 230, 255},
    {224, 231, 255},
    {225, 232, 255},
    {227, 233, 255},
    {228, 234, 255},
    {230, 235, 255},
    {231, 236, 255},
    {233, 237, 255},
    {235, 238, 255},
    {237, 239, 255},
    {239, 240, 255},
    {240, 241, 255},
    {243, 242, 255},
    {245, 243, 255},
    {247, 245, 255},
    {249, 246, 255},
    {252, 247, 255},
    {254, 249, 255},
    {255, 249, 253},
    {255, 248, 251},
    {255, 246, 247},
    {255, 245, 245},
    {255, 244, 242},
    {255, 243, 239},
    {255, 242, 236},
    {255, 240, 233},
    {255, 239, 230},
    {255, 238, 227},
    {255, 236, 224},
    {255, 235, 220},
    {255, 233, 217},
    {255, 232, 213},
    {255, 230, 210},
    {255, 228, 206},
    {255, 227, 202},
    {255, 225, 198},
    {255, 223, 194},
    {255, 221, 190},
    {255, 219, 186},
    {255, 217, 182},
    {255, 215, 177},
    {255, 213, 173},
    {255, 211, 168},
    {255, 209, 163},
    {255, 206, 159},
    {255, 204, 153},
    {255, 201, 148},
    {255, 199, 143},
    {255, 196, 137},
    {255, 193, 132},
    {255, 190, 126},
    {255, 187, 120},
    {255, 184, 114},
    {255, 180, 107},
    {255, 177, 101},
    {255, 173, 94},
    {255, 169, 87},
    {255, 165, 79},
    {255, 161, 72},
    {255, 157, 63},
    {255, 152, 54},
    {255, 147, 44},
    {255, 142, 33},
    {255, 138, 18},
    {255, 131, 0},
    {255, 126, 0},
    {255, 121, 0},
    {255, 115, 0},
    {255, 109, 0},
    {255, 101, 0},
    {255, 93, 0},
    {255, 83, 0},
    {255, 71, 0},
    {255, 56, 0},
};

#define LIMIT 5e-5

RGB_Struct ConvertTemperatureToRGB(float temperature)
{
    uint16_t index = 0;

    if (temperature > 0)
      index = (uint16_t)((temperature + .25 - LIMIT) / .25);
    
    return TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE[index];
}

int main (void) {
  
  for (float temp = 0; temp <= 2; temp += .05) {
  
    RGB_Struct color = ConvertTemperatureToRGB(temp);
    
    printf ("temp: %.2f    R: %3" PRIu8 "  G: %3" PRIu8 "  B: %3" PRIu8 "\n",
            temp, color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue);
  }
}
```

(**note:** the proper format specifiers for exact-width types are found in `inttypes.h`. For `uint8_t`, the output as an unsigned value uses `PRIu8`. Essentially equivalent to `hhu`. There are a number of questions and answers you can reference on that point)

Above the code simply generates the RGB values for temperatures between `0` and `2` Deg C by `.05` degree increments so you can judge the handling of the `index` values. You can test, tweak and adjust as needed.

Also note, as mentioned in the comment, you should really limit the maximum index value generated to the be valid indexes within your table. You can do that by ensuring the value of `index` is reduced modulo by the number of elements in your table, e.g. if not the zero case, then you can use `index = index % NELEM;` to force a valid index in the return (I'm not sure how much of that code you can change -- I'll leave that to you if you can make those changes - pay attention to the type for `NELEM` when used with `%`) Beneath table, you can define `NELEM` as:

```c
#define NELEM sizeof TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE / sizeof *TEMP_INDEX_TO_RGB_TABLE
```

If you do want to limit `index` to a valid index in your table.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and neat explanation mate!!